# I want to create elevated button and text formfield with same size

Tags: flutter, widget

Also I dont want to give sizes one by one for every widget. I imagine that I give a size for widget and other widgets gets size from the first one. But even I tryed almost everything that I seen, still I couldnt solve this problem. Can you help me guys?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you explain s little better? I have created a bunch of tiles that are the exact same before by basically looping what gets made from a list of titles etc... is that what you mean?

Comment: Add your code for better clarification please

Answer (score 0):

Create a constants.dart file

add

```
const widgetWidth = 100.0;
```

create a widget_box.dart

```
import 'constants.dart'
class WidgetBox extends StatelessWidget {

const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
width: widgetWidth
)
}
}
```

then whenever you want to use that widget just plug in

```
WidgetBox()
```

and when you change the value in the constant file it will change it in the widgetbox.dart value which will update it anywhere you use the class. obviously you can build out whatever you want but this is how you can make one change to the same reproduced widget everywhere.

Comment: If I working on same page and all widgets in the list, this answer can solve my problem. But I try to mean that you imagine I have many of buttons at different pages. In this situation when I set sizes separately for all widgets I must change all the widgets' size one by one.  

You can say that build your own widget. That can solve my problem as well. But imagine again, if I want to create different widgets (elavetedbutton, textfield, container etc.) at different pages and I want to make them all the same size. Which way is most usefull now?

Comment: @BerkayAtalay check my updated answer, you are hard to understand and without you actually showing what you have coded I can only guess what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its helpfull. Im new at overflow. Sorry  about that.

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
    

      class SignInView extends StatefulWidget {
      const SignInView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<SignInView> createState() => _SignInViewState();
    }
    
    
    
    class _SignInViewState extends State<SignInView> {
    
      var _identifier;
      var _sifremiUnuttum;
    
    
      double _height = 56; // dummy height
      GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          setState(() {
            // height of the TextFormField is calculated here, and we call setState to assign this value to Button
            _height = globalKey.currentContext!.size!.height;
          });
        });
      }
        
            TextFormField(
                          key: globalKey,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Email Addres',
                            hintText: 'Email Addres',
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 249, 249, 249),
                            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.green
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                // style: BorderStyle.none,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  style: BorderStyle.none,
                                  color: Colors.green
                              ),
                            ),
                            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                // style: BorderStyle.none,
                                  color: Colors.green
                              ),
                            ),
                            // border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            //     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
                            // ),
        
                          ),
                        )


ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: (){},
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(globalKey.currentContext?.size)
                    ),
                    child: Text('Giriş Yap')
                )
```